# How do I programmatically trigger an “input” event without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I installed an event handler on an `input` using

```
var element = document.getElementById('some-input');
element.addEventListener('input', function() {
    console.log('The value is now ' + element.value);
});
```

As expected, the handler is triggered when I type into the text field, but I also need to invoke this handler from my code. How can I simulate the `input` event so that my event listener is called?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click

Comment: @user2473779 The answer there implies that I should do `element.input()`, but that’s not a valid method.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/rHMCy/4/ : check this fiddle from @Juan Mendes' answer

Comment: @user2473779 The function given there doesn’t handle “input” events. See [this modified version of the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbu9jmjj/), which uses an input element instead of an a element. Editing the text triggers the event listener but clicking the button just produces an error.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Create an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object, and [dispatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) it:

```
var event = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true,
});
  
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/6kts64s5/1/)

This is not supported in IE, for that the old-fashioned way has to be used:

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent('input', true, false);

element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: @jeff-h From MDN: Older versions of IE supported an equivalent, proprietary EventTarget.fireEvent() method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Comment: A note: the default input event is not cancelable

Comment: modern copy paste: `element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }))`

Comment: How is this difference from `new InputEvent()` and when should InputEvent be used instead?

Comment: InputEvent is a newer Spec by MDN and not yet HTML standard, albeit widely supported. If you don't need it, I would simply use "Event" for it's been here forever and won't change much anymore. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39925#issuecomment-669550088

Comment: Even with jQuery installed, I would recommend using `dispatchEvent()` over jQuery `$elm.trigger('input')`, because the former is caught by `addEventListener()` and jQuery `$elm.on()`, whereas the latter is caught only by `$elm.on()`.

Answer (score 37):

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Answer (score 22):

If you are using react, following will work:

```
const valueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.textInputRef, 'value').set;
const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this.textInputRef);
const prototypeValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, 'value').set;
if (valueSetter && valueSetter !== prototypeValueSetter) {
    prototypeValueSetter.call(this.textInputRef, 'new value');
} else {
    valueSetter.call(this.textInputRef, 'new value');
}
this.textInputRef.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```

Comment: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.textInputRef, 'value') -> returns undefined, sometimes.

Comment: YES - thank you.  Was pulling my hair out on this when I realized the client site was a react app.  Worked great when no other change or keypress methods were working and the textarea would just revert to blank upon losing focus.  This fixed it and triggers the change event as needed.