# How to type text to input text using Javascript (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript

You can set the value of a input like this:

```
document.getElementById("location-search").value = "Somewhere";
```

but how do you actually trigger type event using Javascript and without using jQuery?

Comment: what you mean type event?. Can you little bit elaborate this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a keypress/keydown/keyup event in JS/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery) the vanilla JS answer is right there if you scroll down to here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542647/2008111

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events

Comment: @Sivabalan he means typing on the keyboard "type"

Comment: assuming you have Id 'form' you can call document.getElementById("form").submit();

Comment: you mean trigger some event when some value added proramatically  ?

Comment: @caramba Sorry i mistake. i think you have edited your comment Or i eyes are bad. I removed the comment

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659430/how-do-i-programmatically-trigger-an-input-event-without-jquery

Comment: One more option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom events. Fire an event when ever you add value to input. And add a listener against this event.

```js
var type = new CustomEvent("typing", {});
function typed() {
    document.getElementById("d").value = "Somewhere";
    document.dispatchEvent(type);
}


document.addEventListener("typing", function(e) {
    console.log("Something typed");
});

typed();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="d" />
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: I mean, I really need to trigger real keyboard type event because I am using PhantomJS and that typing needs to be triggered so certain function will be triggered in the website.

Answer (score 0):

Using the approach mentioned : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542647/7148391)

The change would the event type instead of `HTMLEvents` we use `KeyboardEvent`.

```js
document.getElementById("d").addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += '</br> keydown Triggered'
});


document.getElementById("triggeringStuff").addEventListener('click',function(){
    var str = "Something";
    var elem = document.getElementById("d");
    str.split('').map(function(item){
        var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
        e.initEvent('keydown');
        elem.value += item;
        elem.dispatchEvent(e);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="d" />

<button id="triggeringStuff">Trigger Stuff</button>


<p id="log">Logs :</p>
```