# Setting an input value on a website that resets it on click

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frameworks, dom-manipulation

I'm not able to fully set an input's value by using `input.value = 'Value';`.
It does get set, but it's not really recognized as a written input, because after a click on the input, it gets reset to the last user input.
This only happens on websites with a specific framework or event listeners.
How can I set the value persistently?

You can test it for example on http://instagram.com/accounts/login (it uses the same mechanism)

Comment: Try using http://instagram.com/accounts/login (I did a typo)

Comment: I imagine a solution would involve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659430/how-do-i-programmatically-trigger-an-input-event-without-jquery but I couldn't figure out an event that worked