# How to save input values on server using puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, chromeless

How to save input fields value on server ? i want to save form value after i submit the values disappears  when i reopen the form .

```
 await page.$$eval("input[data-bind='value: SyringeOut']",el=>{
            for(i=0; i<el.length; i++){
                el[i].value=3; 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`page.$$eval` does the following,

- Runs a `querySelectorAll` inside the page.
- Creates an array from the result.
- Maps over the array for you. So it returns a single element and runs your function through it.

Consider rewriting your example like below,

```
await page.$$eval("input[data-bind='value: SyringeOut']", element => element.value = 3)
```

So you should not do a for loop inside the `el => {}` block. Since it's a single element.

Comment: it only put value in first input field . while others remain empty, with for loop it works but values does not save with form.

Comment: You probably trying to fill up a angular/react/vue form. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56299180/6161265

Answer (score -1):

all i have to first double click on input element then type figure/value in it. the final code look like this

```
await page.$$("input[data-bind='value: SyringeOut']").then(async(ee)=>{
        for(var i=0; i<ee.length; i++){
            await ee[i].click({clickCount:2});
            await ee[i].type('3');
            }

    });
```