# Unit Testing of Angular Directive returning failure

Tags: javascript, angular, directive

I have a directive numbersOnly which applied to input type textbox.
Here is my Component HTML

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productIndex"
               required
               numbersOnly
               name="productId"
               placeholder="Enter Product Index"
               #postProduct
               (keyup)="onProductAdd(postProduct)"
                />
```

A very simple directive which restricts from entering any alphabet

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[numbersOnly]'
})
export class NumbersOnlyDirective {

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
    const initalValue = this._el.nativeElement.value;
    this._el.nativeElement.value = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
    if (initalValue !== this._el.nativeElement.value) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when writing the Unit test case using jasmine, it is always showing me an error. Below is my UT file. (Note: Keydown event is getting fired)

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NumbersOnlyDirective } from './numbers-only.directive';
import { Component, DebugElement, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  template: `<input numbersOnly type="text" name="productId"  />`
})
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-unnecessary-class
class TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent {
 //  allowNumbers = true;
}
fdescribe('Directive: numbersOnly', () => {
  let component: TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent>;
  let inputEl: DebugElement;


  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent, NumbersOnlyDirective],
      schemas:      [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name="productId"]'));
    fixture.detectChanges();   
  });

  it('keydown input', () => {
    const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'F' });
    inputEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    expect(event.defaultPrevented).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

Comment: What is the error you are talking about? I do not see anything prevents default in the directive so I wonder why you check for `defaultPrevented`?

Comment: @Shlang I have edited the question now. The test case is being failed.

Comment: You dispatch a `keydown` event but the directive has nothing to do with it since it listens to `input` event.

Comment: Then how can this be modified to successfully run the test case ?

Comment: You could [dispatch the needed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659430/how-do-i-programmatically-trigger-an-input-event-without-jquery)