# How to create `oninput` event on input[text] element with jsdom?

Tags: javascript, jsdom

This my jsdom setup. I want to test oninput event for `input[text]` element. How can trigger `oninput` event? Because just setting `element.value` do not trigger this event.

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;      
    suiteSetup(() => {
        return JSDOM.fromFile("./views/index.html", {
          runScripts: "dangerously",
          resources: "usable"
        }).then(dom => {
          global.dom = dom
          global.window = dom.window;
          global.document = dom.window.document;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35659572/19068), you can create an Event object and use it to trigger the `input` event by executing the JS.

Since you are using JSDOM, you can do that in the context of the page through `eval`.

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const dom = new JSDOM(
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <input>
        <p>Hello world</p>

        <script>
            document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", event =>
                document.querySelector("p").textContent = event.target.value
            );
        </script>`,
    {
        runScripts: 'dangerously',
        resources: 'usable',
    }
);

dom.window.eval(`
    const input = document.querySelector("input");
    input.value = "New value";
    const event = new Event('input', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    });
    input.dispatchEvent(event);
`);

console.log(dom.serialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't improve the previous answer because I get the error: `edit queue is full`.

Since `jsDOM` gives you a near complete browser environment, you don't need the `eval`. You can trigger the event directly from Node.

```js
const input = dom.window.document.querySelector("input");
input.value = "New value";
const event = new Event('input', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
});
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```