# Why tweaking this input field value with JavaScript in the browser console does not behave exactly as manually inserting the value?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, input-field

I am trying to play with some data insertion on forms of [this website](https://ito.intuit.com/). I can manually put my cursor on inputs and type digits, such as `999`. If I reload the page, the value that I typed is still there.

I can access this value by using Google Chrome console (on dev tools) and using the element ID `OSICtrlE1-23`:

```js
> document.querySelector("#OSICtrlE1-23").value 
'999'
```

Ok. **Apparently**, until some point, I can also mutate this value using JS and the console:

```js
> document.querySelector("#OSICtrlE1-23").value = 888
```

It seems to work on the UI. I can see the new value on the UI.

Also, it seems to work on the console when I request the value on the console with JS:

```js
document.querySelector("#OSICtrlE1-23").value 
'888'
```

Unfortunately, if I refresh the page, the value on the UI goes back to `999` (which was the previous value manually inserted).

1 - Why is this happening?

2 - Could the website be restricting what I can do with the console? If so, how to know?

3 - Which command on the console should I be using in order to have the data inserted by computation behaving exactly as the data manually inserted?

Comment: This is most likely related to state or a cache of some kind. Directly editing an element's value via dev-tools bypasses many of the events usually associated with inputs (onChange and the like).

Comment: Thanks, @Yulian. And how to solve this? Is it possible?

Comment: I've never heard of a use-case like this before, my guess would be it's not. You can try using the React Dev Tools extension in Chrome/Firefox to directly mess with components/methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@[Yulian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8594635/yulian) was correct. After carefully inspecting how events were being handled, a reverse engineering endeavor found out that `blur` was the key.
Hence, dispatching the event did the trick!

See the code that works as expected:

```js
const updateInput = (value) => {
   const input = document.querySelector("#OSICtrlE1-23");
   input.value = value;
   input.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the secret behind dispatching the right event ,
@Pedro's solution works for most cases
but this solution worked for me

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles:true}));
```

Source
[How do I programmatically trigger an “input” event without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659430/how-do-i-programmatically-trigger-an-input-event-without-jquery)