# How to trigger oninput event after insert string to textbox with JS?

Tags: javascript, oninput

I want insert a string into textbox by below JavaScript code:

```
document.querySelector('textarea').value = '0a06282c0241057a10011805220d080510bea3f493062a03010c1628f1a6f493063002382b4001481482010f383634333233303532343736343839';
```

1- The first mode: After execute the above code, When I just click on submit button result not work because `oninput` event not enable.

Result 1 is empty and not work :

[image]

---

2- The second mode: After execute the above code, When I enter one (or more) space to textbox then click on submit button, result work perfectly because `oninput` event activated.

[image]

---

How can I active `oninput` event with JS?

Note 1: I'm not owner the website and I have not back end code for change or find `oninput` event function for call the function directly .

Note 2: I run the JS code in browser console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I programmatically trigger an “input” event without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659430/how-do-i-programmatically-trigger-an-input-event-without-jquery)

Comment: @0stone0 I cant understand. Exact witch post answer  is my answer ? you have code? give me a code? Why you close my question :@

Comment: @henrry, your question has not been closed. Check the link provided and see if it's relevant to your situation.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of approaches to consider. The "hard way" would be to construct an InputEvent and submit it to the message pump.

```
const event = new InputEvent(...);
textarea.dispatchEvent(event);
```

But I think an easier way would be to save a reference to the function you register to the event listener, and just call that directly:

```
var inputHanlder = function(...) {};
addEventListener("input", e => { inputHandler(/*event properties*/) });
...
// some kind of sequence of events that loads the text area
inputHandler(...);
```

You might choose the hard way if you have limited access to the event registration or the input handler function.

Comment: Thanks for Answer. But  I'm not owner the website for change or find `oninput `event functions.  I run the JS code in browser console.

Comment: Then you can do the "hard way" to create an event in the console, and execute the dispatch function.

Comment: How can I do? Can you give me a code?

Comment: I did -- you need to supply the details.  Stack Overflow is not a "code for hire" service.

Comment: Thanks, but I cant understand how can I use `InputEvent(...)` or `function(...)`  in browser console.